# Dealing with an employee that went over my head

Tags: people-management

I manage a small team and recently hired for a new position. In the job posting it clearly stated that the work hours are from 8:00-4:30. No concerns about these hours were mentioned during the interview process at all.

Recently after accepting the job offer, the new hire expressed an issue with the hours of work, and proposed their own hours. The hours were not even consistent every day, they requested different work hours for each day of the week (they did all add up to the same total number of hours). I rejected this request.

The employee(before the first day of work), then emailed my superior with the same request and was approved.

How do I carry on managing an employee that is willing to go right over my head on an issue like this?  How do I address this with my manager so that it doesn't happen again.  ( the first words out of my managers mouth should have been "Have you discussed this with your direct manager first?" )

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56132/discussion-on-question-by-cruncher-dealing-with-an-employee-that-went-over-my-he).

Comment: What sort of industry? Did you make it clear during the interview and/or  with the offer that those were the specific, non-negotiable hours they would be required to work?

Comment: Why do you have a pointless set-time day when your own superior thinks more flexible hours is acceptable?

Comment: Your employee did the correct thing. There was a conflict and they escalated. The only issue is between you and your superior disagreeing on what work hours should be (or disagreeing on how such escalations should be resolved, i.e. we agree to always discuss them first).

Comment: OP, it's clear that we need more information about the interaction to give a solid answer. e.g. if you were very polite or depending on your phrasing you may have unintentionally made it sound like _"I would like to approve your request, but this time hours come from above"_, which makes his action the most reasonable one (the employee may even had thought he was doing you a favor!).

Comment: Again, it hinges on information we lack, but immediately assuming _"they disregard my authority"_ because they escalate an issue is not a great quality for a manager, especially if they hasn't started yet. How can they disregard you if he has barely met you?

Comment: Do the same, go to your manager's manager and tell on him give him a taste of his own!

Comment: It's quite possible that as a leader of a small team, you dole out work and lead standups etc. Deciding what core hours are is not within your remit. You seem to be focusing on "oh noes he won!" when you should be focusing on getting them upstairs to acknowledge that you're all entitled to flexible working!  Winner, dinner, etc.

Comment: @GuyShapter Carefull, this one is the oldest.

Comment: No offense, but i would have done the same. The one hiring & paying me makes that decision. Not a manager of a team i'm not even in yet.

Comment: Are you the *manager* of the team, or the *leader* of the team? In other words, do you actually hire and fire people, or just supervise them? I wonder whether there isn't a misunderstanding over what your role in the company actually is.

Comment: Is the set work day a policy (perhaps inherited from your predecessor, or your supervisor's predecessor)? More importantly, is there a compelling reason for everyone on the team to work the same hours?

Comment: "I rejected this request." Did you offer a compelling reason? Or did you simply reject the request without explanation?  One way to avoid having your report go over your head is to explain your reasoning and be persuasive, rather than being dictatorial.  If you have difficulty defending your expectations for working hours, then perhaps you should reevaluate those expectations.

Comment: Unless the position is directly customer-facing (and quite possibly even then), then having arbitrarily set work hours of 8:00-4:30 for no justifiable reason is not just unproductive, but pointless, and possibly losing you talent (How would single parents handle it?) (As to "It states the hours in the job posting...", does it state them in the offer letter or contract? Maybe the interview process proved that the fixed hours were arbitrary and unnecessary. Were those hours only set by you, for your group, or only some, not all, of your team? Just because you slipped that into the job posting...

Comment: The key that really controls what the answer to this question is.... why is it important to have those set hours for everyone to have, why is it a problem for there to be exceptions, why did your manager feel it was a good idea to override you?

Comment: Where are you? In some countries  you would definitely be in the wrong. For example in the UK "All employees have the legal right to request flexible working - not just parents and carers." and "Employers must deal with requests in a ‘reasonable manner’." [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/flexible-working/overview)

Comment: I don't see an issue here. You were contacted first, you rejected it. So the next obvious step was to go a level higher. The chain of command wasn't broken. If anything, you are in an embarrassing situation now.

Answer (score 389, accepted):

> How do I carry on managing an employee that is willing to go right
>   over my head on an issue like this?

This is not a problem with the employee. This is a problem between *you* and *your superior*.

As a middle-level manager, I would be aghast if my boss allowed someone to go around me and get their acceptance on such a request without even first letting me know about it.

I'd immediately request a one-on-one meeting with my boss and discuss what my role was, what my authority was, and why this end-around happened.

Hopefully I would hear that this was all a mistake or misunderstanding. But if I found that I actually had no real authority and that this sort of thing would continue to happen, I'd re-evaluate my role and decide if it was still a role that I wanted to fill or not.

And if I chose to stay, I'd talk with my manager about why the hours of 8:00-4:30 were important enough to make them part of the job posting, and how I was going to move the new employee back to those hours. (This all assumes that coverage of those hours wasn't arbitrary and that adherence really was important).

I would then inform the upcoming employee of the work hours I expected to be covered, and I'd prepare for the scenario where the new employee chose to not come aboard after all.

I view backing up middle-managers (at least publicly) as vitally important in a workplace. I wouldn't work for a company where I was expecting my decisions to be undermined on a regular basis.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56131/discussion-on-answer-by-joe-strazzere-dealing-with-an-employee-that-went-over-my).

Answer (score 69):

### First and foremost, talk to your superior.

You've got to start out by realising that this is not a problem with your employee, if anything, it's a problem with your boss.  Unless it is typically his / her responsibility to set your employees hours, (s)he's out of his / her department by approving the request.

It is quite probable that (s)he didn't know that the employee's original request was denied, and it is just possible that (s)he believed that the employee, being new to the company, wasn't quite sure where to put in the request.

Whatever the case, ***communication with your boss is critical.***  (S)he should know that you had already rejected the request, and it is a good idea for you to have an idea why your boss approved the request.

From there, you should discuss with your superior what this should look like in the future, whether or not those hours should be preserved, etc.  Be ready to express the concerns you had with the employee's suggested hours.  ***Communicate, communicate, communicate.***

*N.B.:  Obviously, when you talk to your boss, don't go in an attitude of "I'm right, you're out of line: I've got to fix you": the whole goal is communication and understanding.*

Answer (score 38):

Read the employee handbook.  Everywhere I've ever worked, escalation to your boss's boss is **exactly** how disagreements with your boss are supposed to go.  Chances are that your employee has done the right thing, if they believe a reasonable request has been unreasonably refused.  If you're going to complain about your employee not following the letter of their contract, you'd better make sure you're also following the letter of their contract!

As Joe Strazzere says though, you do have a problem with your superior overriding your decision without consulting you.  They may quite legitimately decide that your decision wasn't right - and that's why they're **your** boss.  I'd be worried if this was to happen without consulting me, because although flexible hours are usually a good thing, there may be some specific issue which your boss doesn't know about which in this case would make it impractical.

Answer (score 13):

Turn this employee's perceived liability into an asset. Your view is this employee has demonstrated a lack of respect for authority. Turn it around and say, this employee has assertiveness and is a problem solver. It took some guts to go around you. Most people would have given up and lived with the rigid situation. This employee found a way to resolve it. It depends on the job, but this employee's ability to cut through rules and bureaucracy could be a huge asset to you.

Comment: James, Please tell me you're the employee he's talking about. It would be hilarious if it were you.

Answer (score 5):

This question needs more replies from employee's standpoint. Here is one more.

Company work hours by default don't mean everyone has to work them. They only mean company business hours, when someone can come in. Small companies usually have the most flexibility in this regard, so it's natural for people to assume that flexible hours is a norm for non-customer facing roles. Is this a helpdesk or sales position? Is it a software developer / network admin / another technical role? Two different treatment plans.

Regarding how to deal with this or similar situation (when employee requests a non-standard accommodation), you need to try your best to accommodate them. Talk to your boss, see what you can do. If you can allow some flex in work start/end time, do so. If after all this you are absolutely sure hours are strict, you **must** provide a reasonable explanation why this would be the case (unless it's obvious to everyone, like a bank teller - need to cover a specific shift). In 2017 you cannot just reject them "because I said so".

But the key question here is how talented the employee is. Is he/she a top performer / Will become a top performer? Another key question - are you paying as much as google? If yes to the first question and no to the second, you need to be careful when imposing authority. Especially if dealing with a millennial. Especially if they were hired at a senior level position with substantial experience. Based on how they acted, there is a high chance of them being a top performer, now or in the future. [Please respect A players and use their energy in the right way](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/88117/18504), if you want them to succeed.

Comment: I agree, it wasn't worth a down vote. It would have been nice if the person who had down voted you had left a comment as to why they did so though.

Answer (score 1):

I agree absolutely with earlier answers: talk to your manager about him/her overriding your decision without consulting you.  I want you to think about the management implications.

You cannot allow this employee to work flexible hours and not allow the rest of the team to work flexible hours.

How flexible are these hours?  Are there core hours, say 9:00 to 4:00 or 10:00 to 3:00, when everyone must be present?  Can I work 8:30 to 7:00 Monday to Thursday and take Friday off? Can I accumulate overtime and then take the odd day off or get extra pay?  Can I leave early even if an important task needs to be completed by 4:30?

If everyone arrives at 8:30 and leaves at 4:30, it is easy to manage time.  If everyone can arrive and leave at their own time, you need a time management system.  Will you have a clock-in/clock-out system or will you trust everyone to create their own timesheets.  How will you calculate the actually hours worked?  Will you employ someone to process the clock cards or timesheets?  Will the clock-in/clock-out system create weekly reports?  Will staff enter their timesheets into an online system?

A change from fixed hours to flexible hours will be popular with employees but will need rules and extra management.  Who will set the rules?  Who will be responsible for the extra management?

Comment: “You cannot allow this employee to work flexible hours and not allow the rest of the team to work flexible hours.” — In fact, if this is regulated in the contract you absolutely can. It’s entirely normal for different employees to have different working hours. Although, admittedly, in the same team this may lead to friction if there’s no evident, acceptable reason for such a distinction (but even that happens).

Comment: @KonradRudolph.  The question implies that 8:30 to 4:30 are the contract hours and flexible hours are a favour for the new employee.  Having some full time and some part time employees is not unusual and would not be a issue.  You can have secret differences in terms (A gets more per hours than B for the same work) but, in my experience, having obvious differences (A has flexible hours whilst B does not) leads to such a drop in morale and productivity that it is not worth it even if it is legal.

Comment: I tend to agree but then the same is true for other contract terms. Case in point: I’m a postdoc in a big lab, and I have a higher starting salary than my postdoc colleagues. The reason? I negotiated for a higher salary, the others didn’t (since it’s not usual to do this in academia). That’s a ridiculous situation but most people accept it without batting an eyelid. I don’t see why flexible working hours should be any different. In fact, I think that it’s much less serious than variable salaries.

Comment: "If everyone arrives at 8:30 and leaves at 4:30, it is easy to manage time. If everyone can arrive and leave at their own time, you need a time management system." Or you could just have a little faith in your employees.

Comment: There's always the possibility that some people _like_ working 8:00 to 4:30 every day and don't value flexibility at all, while others appreciate or need more flexibility.

Comment: @KonradRudolph The (huge) difference, is that flexible hours are in other peoples faces *every single day*, while different salaries are either confidential, or at least not that obvious (I'm assuming you don't have a big sign above your desk saying "I'm paid more!").

Comment: I think there was a definite "and not have it blow up in your face when the rest of the team figures it out" implied in that statement, as opposed to an absolute statement.

Answer (score 1):

You are not happy with your manager. You say "How do I carry on managing an employee that is willing to go right over my head on an issue like this? How do I address this with my manager so that it doesn't happen again. ( the first words out of my managers mouth should have been "Have you discussed this with your direct manager first?" )"

Who says that wasn't his first words? And then the new employee said "I did, and he rejected it for no good reason at all".

It seems you have your view of the interview process. But if I see a job offer that is mostly fine but I don't like the hours advertised, I would apply and at some point in the interview process discuss the hours. It's quite possible that this was actually discussed, between new employee and your manager. That would explain a lot.

You seem to be particularly annoyed that the requested hours were not the same every day. Why? I know people who need everything to happen in a fixed arranged pattern that they cannot deviate from. This seems more like your problem.

So you have an employee who disagreed with your decision and who completely rightfully went to your manager who overrode your decision. **That's absolutely normal**. How do you carry on managing him? To the best of your abilities, of course. Without creating a hostile working environment by showing or even having anger, or retaliating in any way. By acting professionally. A business decision has been made. **Nothing to take personal**.

How do you address this with your manager so that it doesn't happen again? You have a talk with your manager, asking why the decision was made, and why it was made without asking you. Then you either accept your manager's decision or you go to his boss. If your boss doesn't like it, you can show him this post. On the other hand, you may discover there was a good reason for this decision.